# PHP imap, CSS from the Mailbody destroy site layout

Tags: php, html, css, email, imap

I want to display emails in my site, by using PHP imap. It works fine. 
But when I display the HTML- Body of the mail, the CSS rules destroy my site layout.

```
<div id="mail"><?php echo $mail->HTMLbody; ?></div>
```

I write a function, for looking and deleting the CSS rules in `$mail->HTMLbody`, it works but some of the CSS rules are necessary for the mail-layout.

I have only the idea, t look in the string and add infront of each rule '#mail', but I hpe there is better to do this. Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question. Unless you want to load $mail inside of an iframe any CSS rules included in it will apply to the entire document. I would use the method you described and add #mail to the beginning of each CSS rule.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an `iframe` to display the emails because all the css in the `iframe` wont affect the rest of the site but still display the email properly. I would also recommend enabling `sandbox` on the `iframe` to prevent javascript executions. [More info](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox)

Comment: I think you've nailed it. An `iframe` solves a lot of potential security problems too.

Comment: @SebastianGl. Glad i could help, but i would like to reccomend you read into the `iframe` sandbox attribute to prevent some potential security hazards.